# Multiple Facebook Images using FB.ui?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-ui

How do I use `FB.ui` to make a feed dialog post box that gives user multiple images to choose from? I am using the following code to create the pop up:

```
FB.ui({

      display: 'popup',
      method: 'feed',
      name: 'title here',
      link: 'url.com',
      picture: 'picturepath.jpg',
      caption: 'caption text', // caption
      description: 'long text'

      }, callback);
```

Is there an option to add multiple pictures here?